# Односвязный список с множеством аргументов

Tags: c++, список, односвязный-список

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Имеется 3 класса(один базовый, два производных), и связной список(шаблонный), данные из этих трех классов я помещаю в список, и вывожу. Проблема заключается  в том что при выводе данных на экран срабатывает вывод только для базового класса а его производные не выводятся.
Возможно чтото с выводом списка не так?

Comment: используется язык С++

Answer (score 1):

Используйте виртуальные функции.

Например,

```
struct Base {
  virtual void print(ostream& o);
};

inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, Base& b) {
  b.print(o);
  return o;
}
```

Comment: Для работы со списком использую перегрузку оператора << вывода. Его вроде нельзя виртуальным сделать

Comment: Программа крашится с ошибками LNK2019: unresolved external symbol,
 LNK2001: unresolved external symbol. Пытался уже так сделать, ответы на ошибки не смог найти

Comment: Окей, сейчас буду пытаться исправить

Comment: исправил путем добавления реализации в файл обьявления, хоть это и не есть правильным. 
Проблема всё та же, выводит только базовый обьект(аж три раза). Как я понимаю теперь список не может понять какой ему обьект нужно выводить и выводит базовый три раза. Возможно это проблема в функции вывода списка?(код привел выше)